# value of $k$ in probability

Tags: probability

> In a workshop, there are $5$ machines and the probability of any one of them to be out of service on a day is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{4}.$ If the probability that at most $2$ machines will be out of service on the same day is $\displaystyle \bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)^3k,$ Then $k$ is

what i try

probability of at most $2$ machine will be out of service is

exactly $2$ machine out of service+exactly $1$ machine out of service+exactly $0$ machine out of service

probability of machine out of service is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{4}$

and probability of machine on the service is $\displaystyle \frac{3}{4}$

$$\bigg(\frac{1}{4}\bigg)^2\cdot \bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)^3+\bigg(\frac{1}{4}\bigg)\cdot \bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)^4+ \bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)^5=\bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)^3\cdot \frac{13}{16}.$$

but answer given as $\displaystyle k=\frac{17}{8}$

How do i solve it Help me please

Comment: You need to distinguish the machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\binom52\bigg(\frac{1}{4}\bigg)^2\bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)^3+\binom51\bigg(\frac{1}{4}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)^4+\binom50\bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)^5=\bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)^3\left(\frac{10}{16}+\frac{15}{16}+\frac{9}{16}\right),$$
where the binomials $\binom nk$ stay for number of ways to choose $k$ machines which are out of service.